# How to get list of files per revision using SharpSVN

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

I would like to get the list of files that were modified, added or removed in a specific revision using sharpsvn. I can get that info using command line, for example:

```
C:\svn>svn log --verbose -r 123
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r123 | rmercado | 2018-09-26 01:15:18 -0500 (wed., 26 Set. 2018) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/folder/file1.txt
   A /branches/folder/file2.txt
   M /branches/folder/file3.txt
   D /branches/folder/file4.txt

changes made to branch
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You should take a look at the `SvnClient.GetLog()` method: http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnClient_GetLog_4.htm with the arguments class: http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/AllMembers_T_SharpSvn_SvnLogArgs.htm. This should provide you the necessary functionality. Unfortunately, the documentation of SharpSvn is not the best

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below code. **ChangedPaths** Collection in the instance of **SvnLogEventArgs** will contain the details of the files changed in commit. In the below code "svnLog.ChangedPaths" contains the details.

*Extract from one of my Test application.*

```
            Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> SvnLogList = new Collection<SvnLogEventArgs>();
            SvnRevisionRange range = new SvnRevisionRange(new SvnRevision(this.dtpFromDate.Value), new SvnRevision(this.dtpToDate.Value));
            new SvnClient().GetLog(new Uri(this.txtRepoPath.Text.Trim()), new SvnLogArgs(range), out SvnLogList);

            foreach (SvnLogEventArgs svnLog in SvnLogList)
            {
                CommitLogList.Add(new CommitLog(
                    svnLog.Author,
                    svnLog.LogMessage,
                    svnLog.Revision,
                    svnLog.Time,
                    svnLog.ChangedPaths.Select(cp => cp.Path).ToList()
                    ));
            }
```